# Terraria Truffle iOS won't spawn

Tags: ios, terraria-mobile

In my Terraria iOS world I have made a glowing mushroom biome and made 4 houses. The chat keeps on saying the truffle would like to settle down but he has never settled down.

The update is 1.2, can you please help me?

Comment: this is a commen problem... It can be that its just a bug.. or you have not meet all the requirements for a valid housing in the Mushroom Biome.

Comment: @Schism, does [that question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/198467/ios-terraria-truffle-wont-move-in) even have an answer at all?

Comment: @aytimothy I flagged the question as a possible duplicate because it seems very likely that the two questions are asked by the same person &mdash; the writing style (pre-edit) is similar and the other question mentions they already asked the question. I would've flagged the other way, but this one has no answer at all while the other one has an unupvoted one.

Comment: @Schism Well, tbh - Most of the 1-rep posters do write in nearly almost the same style (if not, they always have unnecessary things), but they all have several things in common: **Bad grammar, spelling (not in all cases), punctuation, formatting and nearly everything in a single paragraph without any line/paragrpah break.**

Comment: Plus this one had particularly descent grammar; sentence structure (not paragraph though). *Compared to the one you've marked as duplicate, this one sounds like a proper question written by me (wo. formatting) and the other one sounds like someone's just written out the question from speech, without any pauses of any sort.*

Comment: All we can do now is wait for an answer. If someone answers in the first one you've marked as duplicate, **Then this questions gets a duplicate mark of that question.**.. Otherwise.. Vice versa.